# Can I use a function with async await inside ComponentDidMount in React Native?

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I am using `AsyncStorage.getItem` in React Native.

As soon as the Application loads, I want to get the saved data in the device memory using `AsyncStorage.getItem`. I thought of using `ComponentDidMount()`. So as soon as the components are loaded, I want to run the `AsyncStorage.getItem` automatically and save the data to the array DATA. This way the user will not push any button to start rendering what is saved on the memory of the device.

I used the code below, but I do not see any console.log activity. But the console.log works on my other pages on same program here. It seems the `ComponentDidMount()` did not get executed.

Thanks!

```
 componentDidMount(){
    async () => { 
      try {
        const HomeData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyApp_Homekey')
        return HomeData
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('There was error.')
      }

      if(!HomeData){
        console.log('There are no Dimmer Light saved in the memory.')
      }
      else {
        console.log('There is value in data after getItem.')
        this.setState(DATA = HomeData)
      }
    }
```

Comment: remove async insinde the componentDidMount and use it like:  async componentDidMount() {.... }

Answer (score 1):

As metioned in comment you should use async for componentDidMount as:-

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {

    const HomeData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MyApp_Homekey')

    if(!HomeData){
      console.log('There are no Dimmer Light saved in the memory.')
    }
    else {
      console.log('There is value in data after getItem.')
      this.setState(DATA = HomeData)
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you don't wanna use arrow function just  `async componentDidMount(){ ... }`